# differential equations, exponential population growth

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, word-problem

If p is population and t is time. Does that mean that when  you do dp/dt = 0 you can find the maximum and minimum population

Comment: If there is a min or a max then the slope will be zero at those points. But there may be no min or max except at the start of end, if there is such a thing.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

If it is exponential growth, the function is an increasing function, or its derivative is always positive($\frac{d e^x}{d x}=e^x>0$). The  max and min values are at the boundaries.